# How to enable bounty option in a question?

Tags: support

It seems in some questions I can see the bounty tab but in some I can't.  So how to enable bounty tab in every question?

Comment: Note that it would help us determine what the issue is if you gave examples of questions that you can and can not put a bounty on.

Comment: @ACuriousMind well I have a problem which isn't not my question. It is that can I not put bounty on duplicate questions? For this question problem resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only put a bounty on a question that is older than 2 days. There is no way to enable bountying for questions that are younger than that.